# Flutter HTTPS Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: ok(handshake.cc:363))

Tags: ios, android-studio, ssl, flutter, https

A colleague has given me a Flutter project to try to build the app in iOS (I use a Mac, we both use Android Studio). Everything is ok except for this error:

```
Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: ok(handshake.cc:363))
```

If I use HTTP instead of HTTPS it works obviously. My colleague said he solved by adding this line of code:

```
client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
```

This line of code is also in my project because the source is the same. So why does it work on Android, but not on iOS?

Answer (score 23):

best way for ssl certification problem on all http 
requests

it is work on both platform (android & ios)

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

void main(){
    HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
    runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a security failure?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, unfortunately. `ServerException(originalException: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
 WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242)), parsedResponse: null)`

Comment: 'MyHttpOverrides.createHttpClient' ('HttpClient Function(SecurityContext)') isn't a valid override of 'HttpOverrides.createHttpClient' ('HttpClient Function(SecurityContext?)').

Comment: for those who are facing issues to override, just use `(SecurityContext? context)` instead of `(SecurityContext context)`

Comment: You should really explain what this does, which is to **remove all security protections against person-in-the-middle attacks**.

Answer (score 12):

Old question but my solution was to ensure the time/date set correctly on client

Answer (score 2):

I've found a secure way to do this.

use this code below:

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
      @override
      HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
        return super.createHttpClient(context)
          ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
             if(host == "yourHost"){
               return true;
              }else{
                return false;
               }
          }
      }
    }
```

inside main():

```
HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
```

Comment: This is **absolutely not secure**!  You can set the host to whatever you want in a bad certificate!

Answer (score 0):

1. Download cert from https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-r3.pem
2. Add this file to assets/ca/ Flutter project root directory
3. Add assets/ca/ assets directory in pubspec.yaml
4. Add this code on your app initialization:

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

 ByteData data = await PlatformAssetBundle().load('assets/ca/lets-encrypt-r3.pem');
 SecurityContext.defaultContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());

 runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score -3):

this should work on ios if you have added this line

```
client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) 
=> true;
```

so double check that you are using the same instance of the client for your request, and that you are making the request after you set the badCertificateCallback parameter

Answer (score -4):

Check your https certificate that you are using, i think iOS has more strict measures than android when it comes to https connection. To be on the safe side, try to update your server certificate.